# Replace case-insensitive string in all folder files

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I'm trying to replace a string with another in all files in dir. Trying to use this command

```
 sed 's/foo/bar/' *
```

But it replaces `foo` and not `fOo` or `Foo` and others.

how to find `"foo"` case-INsensitively?

Answer (score 3):

With some `sed` implementations like GNU's or FreeBSD's:

```
sed 's/foo/bar/i' ./*
```

The `i` makes what you need.

If your `sed` doesn't support that non-standard extension, you can always do:

```
sed 's/[fF][oO][oO]/bar/' ./*
```